# To get values from particular dynamic textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In the below code i have a dynamic textbox and javascript function.I want to get value from particular text box by spiliting the value by $ .But my actual result i can get the value from particular dynamic textbox and different textbox by spilting the value by $ .Pls help me to get value from particular dynamic textbox.
Asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" width="200Px"></asp:TextBox>
```

JS:

```
 str = "";
 $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
    str += $(this).val() + "$";
 });
 if (str != "")
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
    alert(str);
```

Comment: can you explain more: what is input and what output you are expecting in str?

Comment: @ Krishna Pal Singh in the above code i have written input type= textbox so it get all textbox values.But i want values from particular  dynamic textbox .Pls tell me what has to change in above code.

Comment: @user3319384 Can you assign an `id` to your dynamic textbox?

Comment: assign some thing(class or id) by which DOM can identify which textbox in dynamic.

Comment: You can use an incrementing postfix number to the id of the dynamically created textboxes to identify them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Just an idea:***

When you create dynamic textfields, give define them with a specific `class` say `dyn`:

```
 str = "";
 $('input[type=text] .dyn').each(function () {
    str += $(this).val() + "$";
 });
 //your furthur codes
```